# What is the necessity of scoping in Dagger 2?

Tags: android, dependency-injection, dagger-2

I understand why we use scope in dagger. But what I can't understand is why scope is necessary? If I understand correctly, scope is used to have singleton object within the scope. But isn't the dependency graph that determines the singleton nature of an object? Meaning, as long as I have the dependency graph, and I use the same dependency tree to inject, I get the same singleton object.

If yes, then this should be achievable with @singleton annotation alone. But I'm forced to create new custom scope when I have to create dependent components.

Answer (score 0):

> If I understand correctly, scope is used to have singleton object within the scope.

A scoped binding instructs Dagger to *always return the same instance across the lifetime of the component*. You've caught a common case, which is Singleton: If you have a component that is intended to have the same lifetime as the application, and you annotate that component as @Singleton, then anything within that component that you annotate as @Singleton will similarly have the same lifetime and lifecycle as the application.

However, as soon as you create multiple Components in Dagger, they necessarily cannot have the same lifecycle: If component B depends on component A, you *must* create component B after you already have an instance of component A. For that reason, it doesn't really make sense for those two scopes to have the same scope annotation--even if *you* happen to know that your application code can treat *both* of those components as long-lived singleton components that you've kept separate only for the sake of clarity, reusability, or parallel code generation. This is also the reason that [you can't have a `@Singleton` component with dependencies](https://github.com/google/dagger/blob/master/java/dagger/internal/codegen/ComponentDescriptorValidator.java#L193-L198): your @Singleton component is meant to best encompass the lifetime of the VM, so if you've created other objects ahead of that to feed in as dependencies, then that is likely to be confusing.

All that said, it's quite easy to create a new scope, and once you do you can use those multiple scopes to represent different logical lifecycles in your application (such as the lifecycle of an Android Activity or Fragment, the lifecycle of a user's login session, the lifecycle of an individual request in a web server, and so forth).